# Comparison logic not working

Tags: java, android, if-statement, logic

I have a 9 names that I need to display in a rotation sequence. Like the image:

[rotation schedule](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jJkxa.png)

As you can see, the names go one position down in the list, with the 9th name taking top of it at each rotation.

The variable that controls the rotation is the integer iName. Theres a method that just reads an user input (an imagebutton touch) and adds or decreases the value of iName. It starts at 0 (list is displayed Adams to Ida), and when the user gives the command it assumes 1 (so the list is displayed from Ida to Henry).
Actually, the user can go back in time and turn iName from 5 to 4, so the list changes from Easy-Denver, to Frank-Easy.

I have 9 TextViews doing this job, and it's updated inside a loop, as follows:

```
int[] arrNames_Ids = {R.id.Name1, R.id.Name2, R.id.Name3, R.id.Name4, R.id.Name5, R.id.Name6, R.id.Name7, R.id.Name8, R.id.Name9};
String[] arrPeople = new String {"Adams","Boston","Chicago","Denver","Easy","Frank","George","Henry","Ida"}
String sAlternative_Name = "";

for (iCounter = 0; iCounter < 9; iCounter++){
    // iName is a global variable, stars at 0, but it changes upon user request:
    sName = arrPeople[iName];
    // this "if" statement is the problematic piece of code.......
    if (((iCounter == 1)||(iCounter == 3)||(iCounter == 5))&& (sName.equals("Adams")){
        sAlternative_Name = mtAlternative_Name();
        sName = sAlternative_Name;
    } else {
        if ((sAlternative_Name != "") && (sName.equals(sAlternative_Name))){
            sName = "Adams";
        }
    }
    // without the previous "if" the following part works properly, so the list rotates accordingly;
    tvNames = (TextView) getView().findViewById(arrNames_Ids[iCounter]);
    tvNames.setText(sName);
    iName = iName + 1;
    if (iName > 8){
        iName = 0;
    }
}

public String mtAlternative_Name(){
    int iCycle;
    String sName_Aux = "";
    // iCurrent_Cycle is a global variable, assumes values from 0 to 73, and it controls the order in which arrPeople is supposed to be shown:
    iCycle = iCurrent_Cycle % 18;
    switch (iCycle){
        case 1: sName_aux = "George"; break;
        case 3: sName_aux = "Easy"; break;
        case 5: sName_aux = "Chicago"; break;
        case 10: sName_aux = "Henry"; break;
        case 12: sName_aux = "Frank"; break;
        case 14: sName_aux = "Denver"; break;
    }
    return sName_Aux;
}
```

The idea is to prevent "Adams" from occupying the positions 1, 3 and 5.
Everytime he's in those positions someone else (sAlternative_Name) takes the place, and "Adams" goes to the position that person was supposed to take.
The array arrPeople doesn't change, example:

If "Adams" was supposed to be in position 4, "Easy" takes the place and "Adams" goes to position 8.
But when the list rotates agains (going foward), "Adams" takes position 5 and "Easy" takes position 9.

I'm new to Java and don't have much experience in programming either, but I can't see what's wrong with this code...

The % operator I use it's to make the names in green to take place in "Adams" position. As you can see, "Boston" and "Ida" are not in the game... but were supposed to be......... this is ok, and I'll manage to think something later, but right now I'd wish I could understand why my code isn't working...

Thanks a lot...

Comment: Have you stepped through the code in your IDE debugger yet? If not, please do so and tell us the point at which the behavior deviates from your expectation, and what the relevant values are.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Right now I can't check it and I don't remember exactly the results I get. I run the app in my phone and a tablet, for testing (the emulator is toooo slow in my computer...). The rotation works, it's just the changing of positions between "Adams" and the sAlternative_Name variable that doesn't work. I'll have to get back in a couple hours with the detailed results.

Comment: First off I don't fully understand the problem you are solving but I think the issue might be in the line: [sAlternative_Name != ""] change it to [!sAlternative_Name.equalsIgnoreCase("")]

Comment: Also you might want to add sAlternative_Name = ""; at the end of else if.

Comment: Yes!!!!!! well, not sure if that's the only problem, but it rings a bell. When I first wrote the lines I was using "==" instead of "equals()", but I didn't pay attention to the "!=" operator...

Comment: Can't make the changes to check it yet, but hopeffuly it will get me there.

Comment: About the problem I'm trying to solve, it's a rotation schedule that I want to implement in my job. We are 9 people who works in 9 different positions, but one person is not able to work in positions 2, 4 and 6. By the way, it reminds me of the second part of my problem... which I said I would think of later, but any help would be appreciated!...

Comment: Syntax error: String array declaration should be `String[] arrPeople={...};`

Comment: Thanks. My mistake... I'm not in the Android Studio right now, and I wrote the code here from memory, which is not much, but mistakes happens... But again, the problem is in the if statement. Without that segment my app does the job, which is to display 9 names in a table, like the columns of the image I've posted. I think what @Abbas said might help. Actually, I felt a little confused when I search for equalsIgnoreCase(), but I'll be at home to try that in about 2 hours. Anyway, thank you.

Comment: `equalsIgonreCase()` simply does the same as `equals()` with one minor difference: it ignores difference of upper and lower cases.
With A = "AA" and a = "aa". `A.equalsIgnoreCase(a)` will return true (Ignoring upper case difference between the strings), but with `A.equals(a);` will return false (It has to be an exact match).

Comment: Wow! It's working now. I made the change @Abbas told me to, and also I had a variable ("iName") with a wrong assignment. I was assigning "iName = Current_Cycle % 9", but in fact I realized it should be "iName = 9 - (iCurrent_Cycle % 9)". Besides the logical operator I was having trouble with the switch statement... I wasn't familiar with the debbuger prior to this question. Only when I started checking each variable that I realized the method "mtAlternative_Name" was giving me a null return.

Comment: And the cases inside the "switch" were wrong for the exact response.

Comment: @RGeral Please check my answer. What the code will do is, if "Adams" is at positions 1,3 or 5, then it is interchanged with Chicago. So, the first row of the round table, which is supposed to be `Adams  Boston  Chicago  Denver  Easy  Frank  George  Henry  Ida` will be `Chicago  Boston  Adams  Denver  Easy  Frank  George  Henry  Ida` I hope this is what you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

The logic I used is that created a 2 dimensional array that held the entire round table (Without Adams being removed from positions 1,3 or 5). Then, another nested loop is run to substitute "Adams" in each row with "Chicago". Finally, the 2 dimensional array is printed. This gives you the output.
(*I took Chicago as the alternate name instead of Easy because at times, Easy can also be at position 1,3 or 5 with respect to Adam's position so the interchange would still cause the exception to persist.*)

```
 String[] arrPeople={"Adams","Boston","Chicago","Denver","Easy","Frank","George","Henry","Ida"};
   String[][] roundtable=new String[9][9];
   int i,j,p;
   for(i=0;i<9;i++){
     p=i;
     for(j=0;j<9;j++){
      roundtable[i][j]=arrPeople[p++];
      if(p==9)
      p=0;
     }
   }

   for(i=0;i<9;i++){
     for(j=0;j<5;j+=2){
       if(roundtable[i][j].equals("Adams")){
        roundtable[i][j+2]="Adams";
        roundtable[i][j]="Chicago";
        break;
       }
     }
   }

   for(i=0;i<9;i++){
   for(j=0;j<9;j++)
   System.out.print(roundtable[i][j]+"\t");
   System.out.println("\n");
   }
```